# Binding: Visualize a list of unnamed booleans using DataTemplate and bindings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I have a ViewModel which contains an ObservableCollection of booleans. And I have a control.
A want to visualize my list of booleans as a list of rectangles with two different colors.
I can't declare such binding. Here is my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateName">
        <Grid Margin="12,0,0,0">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ***PROBLEM***   
                                       , Converter={StaticResource BoolToSelectionBrushConverter}"} 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                       Margin="0" Width="25" 
                                       Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                       StrokeThickness="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateName}" 
                    Margin="0,0,8,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Can I achieve it without creating a wrapper?

```
public class Value 
{
   public bool IsOk{get;set;}
}
```

and binding to named property:

```
      <Grid Margin="12,0,0,0">
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding IsOk 
                       , Converter={StaticResource BoolToSelectionBrushConverter}}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                       Margin="0" Width="25" 
                       Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       StrokeThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have my WP7 development environment handy currently, so it's untested, but I think the following should work:

```
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True,
                              Converter=BoolToSelectionBrushConverter}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                               Margin="0" Width="25" 
                               Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               StrokeThickness="0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding .,Converter=BoolToSelectionBrushConverter}"... />
```